# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'todos')

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I try to run this code it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'todos')

how to fix it

I wanted to make a todo list that will work after the user registers, but todo does not work after registration

My code:

HomePage.js

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { isAuth, email } = useAuth();

  return isAuth ? (
    <div>
      <TodoForm />
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(removeUser())}>
        Log out from {email}
      </button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
};
```

TodoForm.js

```
const TodoForm = () => {  
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todo.todos)
  // const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todo.todos);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [todoValue, setTodoValue] = useState("");
  const addTodoHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const todo = {
      id: v4(),
      text: todoValue,
      completed: false,
    };

    dispatch(addTodo(todo));
    setTodoValue("");
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTodoValue(e.target.value);
  };

  console.log(todos);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={addTodoHandler}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={todoValue}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Add task"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <TodoList key={todo.id} todo={todo} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

todoSlice.js

```
const initialState = {
  todos: [],
};
export const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.todos.push(action.payload);
    },

    removeTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.todos = state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
    },

    completedTodo: (state, action) => {
      const toggleTodo = state.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === action.payload);
      toggleTodo.completed = !toggleTodo.completed;
    },
  },
});
```

store

```
  reducer: {
    todo: todoSlice,
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

help me fix this, I will be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

slicename is `todos` not `todo`

```
const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos.todos)
```